# Simplest example of a microservices project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, microservices

I'm trying to learn how to develop a GAE app in a microservices pattern for Python37 Standard Environment. It is a *blackbox* for me to imagine what component of an app should be made into a service and what shouldn't.

My understanding is that each service should represent a 'business' component of the app. Conceptually, this is a bit of a blur to me. For example, if we are building a todo app, how should we divide it into various services?

Another area that I don't understand is how services communicate with each other. According to the documentation, services call each other using HTTP requests like this:

```
http://[VERSION_ID].[SERVICE_ID].[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
```

Does this mean that we use a request library to make a request, like below?

```
import requests 
requests.get(https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com)
```

There are some more aspects of implementing microservices that I don't quite understand yet. With this said, I would like to request a basic code example of a full microservices app. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, if we are building a todo app, how should we divide it
>   into various services?

This logically (and not technically). You would divide your functionality into several API:s which are grouped logically. I work with such API:s which I grouped the following way:

- The "Users API", handling authentication and user-related functionality.
- The "Resource API" which handles creating, viewing and editing the resources which are stored in the data storage. In your case, this could be creating, getting and editing a single TODO list.
- The "Collection API" which handles lists and collections of resources. In your case this could be viewing and grouping several lists of TODO together.
- The "Datastore API" which provides low-level functionality to datastore operations.

The above is just my example. In your case it will depend on your specific functionality and there are many ways to group your APIs but you should group "business logic" together rather than technically.

> how services communicate with each other*?

You want [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) and most often communicate over HTTP and a RESTful API with some preferably human-readable format such as JSON. So one service can make a RESTful connection to the other, send or recieve JSON data and the services will be independent and divided so that you can work and deploy the services independently of one another.

Comment: A book is not enough to answer! DDD (domain driven development) is a good starting point. Microservice have to handle their own data, loosely coupled with other service, with the heavily to scale horizontally and independently to the other services. They can communicate in restful json API, but also with grpc. Service mesh can be deploy to control the services communication,..... So many topics to cover...